# I would like to ask if my answer to this simple circuit is correct?

Tags: circuit-analysis, kirchhoffs-laws

The problem is to find the values of \$ V_x \$ and \$ i_3 \$. I was reviewing DC using KVL and KCL and I would like to check if I got the answers right!

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a "check my work" question.

Comment: Yeah I'm not going to check your algebra, but it looks OK.  (with out the 6 V supply the voltage would be 8V.)  I would have drawn the current into the top node differently, since you've got all the current leaving the node.  But that doesn't make a difference in the algebra... just my electronics sense.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold, I was always hesitant about this as well when I was taking the class where we learned nodal analysis. Either taking the sum of currents entering or the sum of currents leaving a node = 0 simplifies everything; the directions are arbitrary and negative answers result if you assumed an incorrect direction. Otherwise you would have some terms add and some subtract in your expression.

Comment: @sherrellbc Yes, that's my approach too, when I do it methodically. It avoids stupid errors when you're writing down the equations for complex circuits. Of course if there's only a few parts it's often safe to draw the arrows the way you think the current will flow and make them all positive, for example. In this (contrived) example, it's not completely obvious a priori that current is flowing *into* the 6V source (well, you could pretty easily mentally calculate Vx with R2 disconnected as 8V so it has to flow in.. but that's thinking).

Comment: Also, am I wrong here? The directions used for the KVL in each loop do not match the directions assumed for the expression `i2 = i1-i3`.

Answer (score 2):

You got the right answer, but I didn't check your algebra, LOL.

[image]